# Emacs function for hash-character

Tags: function, emacs, if-statement, line

The function below should either insert a `#` if at beginning of the line, and if not, it should go to the end of line and insert a `#`. Why is this not working (it always goes to the end and inserts a `#`?

```
(defun end-of-line-hash () 
  (interactive)
   (if (beginning-of-line)
       (insert "#")  
     (end-of-line)
     (insert "#"))
)
(global-set-key (kbd "#") 'end-of-line-hash)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `beginning-of-line` moves the point to the beginning of the line. It probably returns `nil`. Try this instead.

```
(defun end-of-line-hash () 
  (interactive)
   (if (= (point) (line-beginning-position))
       (insert "#")  
     (end-of-line)
     (insert "#"))
)
```

Comment: Would you know how to extend this by first checking if a region is selected? If a region is selected, it should run "comment-region" instead. That would make the hash-character almighty :)

Comment: I actually did it! I'll post it in the answer :) (This is the most advanced stuff I've done in Emacs)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [rwb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1172486/rwb)'s answer:

```
(defun hash-character-ESS () 
  (interactive)
  (if (region-active-p) 
      (comment-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
    (if (= (point) (line-beginning-position))
        (insert "#")  
      (end-of-line)
      (insert "#")))
)
```

1) If text is selected, comment the region.

2) If point (cursor) is at the beginning of line, insert # character there.

3) If point is not any of the previous two, put the # at the end of the line.